# form not updated after manipluating in callback

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I got a form which holds a list of objects (constants). These are editable.
Up to this point it was possible to for example delete any of them directly - without confirming.
Now I want to change that by simply inserting a (ng)bootbox confirm step.

the actual code which performs the delete operation in my .ts file:

```
   public DeleteMyObjcet(constantName: string): void {

               DeleteConstant(constantName);
               this.ConstantsNavigationForm.$setDirty();

            }
```

the view

```
<ng-form name="Vm.SoftSensorDialogComponent().ConstantsForm">
    <ng-form class="st-table-container" name="Vm.SoftSensorDialogComponent().ConstantsNavigationForm">

        <button type='button' "
                ng-click="Vm.SoftSensorDialogComponent().SoftSensorDialogConstants.DeleteSoftSensorConstant(dataItem.Name)"></button>

    </ng-form>

</ng-form>
```

now this works fine: by deleting any object, the view (form) is beeing updated immediadetly.

and now I add and additional step in my .ts file:

```
public Request_DeleteConstant(constantName: string) {

            let options = {
                message: "<h4>Are you sure you want to delete :" + constantName + " ?</h4>",
                buttons: {
                    cancel: {
                        label: "CANCEL",
                        className: ""
                    },
                    confirm: {
                        label: "OK",
                        className: "",
                        callback: () => {
                            this.DeleteConstant(constantName);
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

            this.softSensorDialog.$ngBootbox.customDialog(options);
        }
```

...now a bootbox confirm is shown after clicking "delete" and before the actual delete operation which is called by its callback.
Unfortunately, the form is not beeing updated after the successfull operation.
How can this be? It must be somehow connected to the callback.
Is there any possibility to refresh/update the form manually?

Answer (score 0):

Problem:
The context got lost by executing the delete operation via callback.

Solution:
passing the context `$scope` and call `$scope.apply()` in the callback